# pdfcrop using luatex engine minimal setup

Tags: luatex, pdfcrop

I want to try the great pdfcrop.pl script by Heiko Oberdiek (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) with LuaTeX engine.

Unfortunately my knowledge about LaTeX tools like LuaTeX is non existent.
I'm looking for miniamalist setup instructions to make it work (on Windows 7 OS).

I downloaded miminal LuaTeX engine files from:
http://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/bin/luatex/mswin/bin/

I'm using --luatex --luatexcmd switches for the script but it throws errors.
I've made a lot of cobbling it together at that point (like copying missing .fmt and other files from other distributions like MikTeX, LeXlive etc..) but I guess it doesn't make sense to describe that exactly as I didn't really know what I was doing ;)

Best would be to start fresh
So given the pdfcrop.pl script and the miminalist LuaTeX engine files - Coould somebody outline steps to make it work?

Thanks a lot!

---

UPDATE
When i'm running this with `--debug` and `--ini` switches:

```
    pdfcropn.pl --debug --hires --gscmd="C:\Program Files\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe" --luatex --ini --luatexcmd="C:\PDFcrop\Luatex\luatex.exe" "CTGov PS model.pdf" "CTGov PS model.crop2.pdf"
```

it gives me this:

`PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

- Restricted mode: disabled
- Option `pdfversion': auto
- Input file: CTGov PS model.pdf
- Output file: CTGov PS model.crop2.pdf
- Margins: 0 0 0 0
- Input file name `CTGov PS model.pdf' contains special characters.
- Copy input file to temporary file `tmp-pdfcrop-11176-img.pdf'.
- PDF header: %PDF-1.5
- Using PDF minor version: 5
- Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
- Ghostscript call: "C:\Program Files\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f tmp-pdfcrop-11176-img.pdf

GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)

Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.

Processing pages 1 through 1.

Page 1

Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.

Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu... 3590604 2239077 5213760 3919818 4 done.

%%BoundingBox: 32 199 555 644

%%HiResBoundingBox: 32.430022 199.070080 554.069936 643.009902

- Page 1: 32.430022 199.070080 554.069936 643.009902
- Running LuaTeX ...
- LuaTeX call: C:\PDFcrop\Luatex\luatex.exe -no-shell-escape --ini --etex -interaction=nonstopmode tmp-pdfcrop-11176

warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/PDFcrop/Luatex;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C:/;C://share/texmf-local/web2c;C://share/texmf-dist/web2c;C://share/texmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C://texmf-dist/web2c;C://texmf/web2c.

This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.78.2 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (rev 4774)  (INITEX)

! I can't find file `tmp-pdfcrop-11176'.

<*> tmp-pdfcrop-11176

Please type another input file name

! Emergency stop.

<*> tmp-pdfcrop-11176

No pages of output.

Transcript written on texput.log.

- Cleanup
- Temporary files: tmp-pdfcrop-11176-img.pdf tmp-pdfcrop-11176.tex tmp-pdfcrop-11176.log

!!! Error: LuaTeX run failed with value 1!`

---

I can see `tmp-pdfcrop-5448.tex` has been created in the directory where original PDF is.

Moreover by manually re-running  luatex command with full path to the tex file it goes further but still breaks:

`C:\PDFcrop>C:\PDFcrop\Luatex\luatex.exe -no-shell-escape --ini --etex -interaction=nonstopmode c:\pdfcrop\tmp-pdfcrop-5448
        warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/PDFcrop/Luatex;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C:/;C://share/texmf-local/web2c;C://share/texmf-dist/web2c;C://share/texmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C://texmf-dist/web2c;C://texmf/web2c.
        This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.78.2 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (rev 4774)  (INITEX)
        (c:/pdfcrop/tmp-pdfcrop-5448.tex
        !LuaTeX error (file tmp-pdfcrop-12368-img.pdf): cannot find image file 'tmp-pdfc
        rop-12368-img.pdf'
         ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pdfcrop` also works without format files (iniTeX mode), if option `--ini` is given:

```
pdfcrop --luatex --ini
```

Or with specifying the binary:

```
pdfcrop --luatex --ini --luatexcmd=/some/where/luatex
```

Comment: OK. I tried this:
C:\PDFcrop>pdfcropn.pl --hires --gscmd="C:\Program Files\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe" --luatex --ini --luatexcmd="C:\PDFcrop\Luatex\luatex.exe" "CTGov PS mode
l.pdf" "CTGov PS model.crop2.pdf"



and I'm getting:



PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories:

Comment: C:/PDFcrop/Luatex;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop
/Luatex/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/share/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/Luatex/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/L
uatex/texmf/web2c;C:/PDFcrop;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/PDFcrop/texmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C:/;C://share/texmf-local/web2c;C://share/texmf-dist/web2c;C://share/te
xmf/web2c;C://texmf-local/web2c;C://texmf-dist/web2c;C://texmf/web2c.
!!! Error: LuaTeX run failed with value 1!

Comment: @Msciwoj: Please add option `--debug` to see the console ouptput of the LuaTeX run. I think, the warning can be ignored. (Also you can edit your question to provide the additional data, a comment is somewhat limited.)

Comment: I did. Updated the question (added two sections). Looks to me like a problem with paths…

Comment: @Msciwoj: What happens, if you create the file `C:\pdfcrop\Luatex\texmf.cnf` with the following line `TEXINPUTS=.`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you! For the files I have I generally see LuaTex engine produces much smaller (~30%) PDF files than MikTex. (Haven't tried 3rd one, pdfTeX yet, actually don't even know if that's possible on Windows). Anyway, thank you very much!!

Comment: Would you have some experience/guidelines to do same on MacOS?

Comment: @Msciwoj no experience.